# ssh-add -c not working: Error reading response length from authentication socket

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm keep getting this error while trying to have the RSA key password asked when connecting to a server. If I try to add a key WITHOUT the pass-check, everything goes ok.
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3):

Because you have not started an agent. Run ssh-agent and evaluate the printed variables in your shell.

e.g:

```
eval `ssh-agent`
```

Comment: No, the agent was started.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/1067301

Comment: Also happens with xfce-terminal v0.6.3 (xfce4) so it might not be only the gnome-keyring bug : `pgrep -l ssh-agent` *3057 ssh-agent*.Fine? not so much: `ssh-add` *Enter passphrase for /path/to/id_ed25519:* <passphrase> *Error reading response length from authentication socket. **Could not add identity**: /path/to/id_ed25519*. `eval $(ssh-agent)` *Agent pid 3071*. Then `ssh-add` *Enter passphrase for /path/to/id_ed25519: **Identity added**: /path/to/id_ed25519*. So it appears that ssh-agent can be running *while* missing the env variables.